# APEX 22.2 Download IR PDF output in new browser window

Tags: pdf, tabs, output, new-operator, apex

I work with APEX 22.2 and I would like to be able to access the code that is behind the DOWNLOAD to PDF so I can set the Printing Output View File as 'Inline' to open in a new tab rather than in the same page.
The behavior for Attachment opens up directly in new tab in Fire Fox, however in Chrome it asks to save on a location without opening the file. (We are using Chrome with APEX 22.2)